# Importing lots of text files and deleting repeated lines

Tags: r

I am working in a set of interviews I got from a database in my work, each in separated text file (a normal file with a transcript in multiple lines).

Each interview is going to be part of a data frame as a variable. The metadata for each interview is in a different data frame, I have to import the texts into it (a whole interview per row). They are over 700 text files to be imported.

The question is, there are a lot repeated lines in the interview files, and due to the number of files, importing one by one and using `x <- unique (x)` is out of the question. I wrote the code bellow to try to import them:

```
files_captions <- list.files(path="path/to/the/files", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
folder_captions <- "path/to/the/folder"    
clean_text <- function(myfile){
  n <- length(myfile)
  myfile <- c(stringr::str_remove_all(myfile[-n], "[\n].*"),
              myfile[n])
  myfile <- unique(myfile)
  myfile <- paste0(myfile, collapse = "\n")
  myfile
}
texts <- ldply(clean_text(files_captions),  read_file)
```

But instead of ending with something like this:
[The result I am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtAsE.png)

all I have is the path to my files

```
View(texts)
V1
path/to/my/files/file1 path/to/my/files/file2
```

My [very final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLQAq.png) would be this

I am open to any solution to this

Thank you!

**Update**

Here is a workflow of what I have been incapable of doing:

1. read 700 texts files from a directory (those are plain text files
   with lines separated by \n)
2. deleting the repeated lines I
3. Importing 
   them into R. It might be a one column vector in which each text is a variable.

***Update 2***

I managed to clean the texts and have them in list:

```
str(teste)
List of 3
 $ : chr [1:205] "Hello " ...
 $ : chr [1:581] "hello little buns  ...
 $ : chr [1:849] "- Hello everybody," ...
```

Now My struggle is to collapse each of this list elements in a single row of a vector or a data frame. Each one is a single text broken into vector lines. I would need each of them to be a single vector.

Comment: Have you tried running the code inside your `clean_text` function line by line on a single file and inspecting the results at each step to see where it's going awry?

Comment: In a single fie basis, it works fine. The problem is that I have 700. I would like to make it a bit more automatic.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand where you're having trouble. If you have a process that works for a single file, you can just iterate it over a vector of the file names using `lapply` or `purrr::map`, right? And then collapse the resulting list of strings into vector with `unlist`.

Comment: I have a number of text files with duplicated lines. I need to import them in a data frame (1 column) in which each variable is a file without the duplicated lines. They are over 700, I can't find a way to get all at once

Comment: This texts are in a directory

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult here, but that just repeats what you said in the question. I still don't get it. Why can't you get a vector of the file names with `list.files()`, iterate your file-loading-and-cleaning function over that vector with `lapply` or `map`, then convert the resulting list to a vector (column) with `unlist`?

Comment: Hi. Because it returns me a list of the file addresses as a vector not the text files itself. I am totally desperate for a solution. I will make an update with the flow of what I have to do. Thank you

Comment: I updated with the question with a workflow

Comment: It sounds like you've got problems at multiple stages, and without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's really hard to help you with a multi-part question like this. I would recommend that you sharpen this question to focus on either the text-cleaning aspect or the iteration aspect with a reproducible example and see where that gets you.

Comment: It looks like you just have your operations out of order. You're getting a vector of path strings, trying to clean the paths, then reading in the file based on this "cleaned" path. You want to get the vector of file paths, read in each one with `read_file`, then run your cleaning function on each result.

Comment: I managed to clean the texts and have them in list:

    str(teste)
    List of 3
     $ : chr [1:205] "Hello " ...
     $ : chr [1:581] "hello little buns  ...
     $ : chr [1:849] "- Hello everybody," ...

Now My struggle is to collapse each of this list elements in a single row of a vector or a data frame. Each one is a single text broken into vector lines. I would need each of them to be a single vector.

Comment: `lapply(yourlist, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "\n"))`

Answer (score 0):

From your update 2, you should be able to just map and paste:

```
purrr::map_chr(teste, paste0, collapse = "\n")
```

You could then combine this with the metadata:

```
fileMetadata %>%
   mutate(interviewText = purrr::map_chr(teste, paste0, collapse = "\n"))
```

Comment: Hi Marcus. Thanks a lot! it made possible the function in the answer bellow!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all helping. I managed to sort out the issue with the following function:

```
files <- list.files(path="path/to/you/files", pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE)
import.and.clean <- function(myfiles){
  tmp <- lapply(myfiles, read_lines)
  tmp2 <- purrr::map(tmp, unique)
  tmp3 <- purrr::map_chr(tmp2, paste0, collapse = "\n")
  return(tmp3)
}
my.vector <- import.and.clean(files)
```